# Solve segmentation fault error in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to store the sum 1/k^2 in an array using this code:

```
int main()
{ 
int i,n, e;
double terms[n];
double x, y;

printf(" Introduce n\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

y=1;
i=0;

while(e<n)
  {
   x=1/((y)*(y));
   printf("x is %.16lf\n",x);
   terms[i]=x;
   printf("terms is %.16lf\n", terms[i]);
   y++;
   i++;
   e++;
  }
}
```

And I get the "segmentation fault" error. Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

I am programming in C

Comment: When you define the array `terms`, what is the value of `n`? You haven't initialized it yet so it is *indeterminate* and seemingly random. The code will not go back and redefine variables retroactively.

Comment: Unrelated, but why a `while` and not a `for`?

Comment: Oh and you also use *other* variables uninitialized. Just don't do that!

Comment: Also, would this even compile because `n` is not compile time defined (for initializing `terms` array)?

Comment: You seem to be using `e` as a doppelganger for `i`. I don't see why you are using two variables there.

Comment: @Neijwiert C99 introduced [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) so it is valid. And C99 also introduced free placement of declarations and definitions, so the definition of `terms` could happen after the initialization.

Comment: Lastly, your code doesn't build. When showing us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), make sure it is a copy-paste of the actual code you try to run. Don't attempt to rewrite the code in the question, as that might introduce unrelated errors (or sometimes even fixing the errors by mistake) like you have done (`terms` or `termes`?)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude for some reason I had no idea that was considered valid. Thanks for the information!

Comment: You have to initialize values of `e` and `n`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, what is the difference between `e` and `i` (beside you not initializing `e`)? What is the purpose of the two variables? If you initialize `e` to zero, then both `e` and `i` will always keep the same values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm surprised `gcc -Wall` doesn't at least warn about `n` not being initialized before the declaration if `-std=c99` wasn't used (I'm assuming `gcc` here, but not sure what the OP is using). Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: @lurker That is a good question, and one I'm not able to answer.

Comment: Simply set `n` to a known value before you declare the array, end of story. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` is garbage in `double terms[n];` that causes undefined behaviour. Enable compiler warning by compiling with `gcc -Wall` and observe. Never ignore warnings.

Initialize `n` before declaring `terms[n]` OR

```
printf(" Introduce n\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
double terms[n];
```

Also `e` is uninitialized, initialize it.

```
 e = 0 ;
 while (e < n){
  /* code */
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

When declaring an array with `n` elements (`double terms[n];`), the allocation of said array is done in the compilation stage. Because you left your `n` variable un-initialized, it has indeterminate value (random from the user perspective), so you don't know what is the size of said array.

Scanning an `int` into `n` later, does not help at all as it is done in the run-time (and also, it is done **AFTER** the array declaration. It could have worked if you have used `malloc` for the allocation **AFTER** the `scanf`).

Anyway, you currently have an array with "random" size, and accessing it is Undefined Behavior -> segfault

Answer (score 2):

The crash comes from undefined size of the `terms[n]` array. You are crossing array memory boundaries.

A few variables are not initialized:

```
double terms[n]; // n is not initialized 

while (e<n){ // e is not initialized
```

You have many choices to properly build `terms` array (marked in the code as well):

1) Decide upfront on the specific size of the array. (This is not flexible approach!)

2) Allocate array dynamically when you read `n`.

3) Declare `terms[n]` after reading `n`.

Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){ 

int i;
int n;
int e = 0;

// 1. One of the 3 choices - thus is a rigid one
// double terms[TERMS_SIZE]; // make TERMS_SIZE big enough,  read n has to be less than TERMS_SIZE

double x, y;

printf(" Introduce n\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

// 2.
// double *terms = malloc ( n* sizeof sizeof(double));

// or

// 3.
double terms[n];

y=1;
i=0;

while (e<n){

    x=1/((y)*(y));

    printf("x is %.16lf\n",x);

    terms[i]=x;
    printf("terms is %.16lf\n",terms[i]);

    y++;
    i++;
    e++;
  }

  // If 2. used free the memory
  // free(terms);

  return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
4
 Introduce n
x is 1.0000000000000000
terms is 1.0000000000000000
x is 0.2500000000000000
terms is 0.2500000000000000
x is 0.1111111111111111
terms is 0.1111111111111111
x is 0.0625000000000000
terms is 0.0625000000000000
```